# resetting root password ovh

Tags: password, root

I've purchased VPS @ ovh.com, I changed my root password and now I cannot remember it, I've followed the steps on their forums but it doesn't seem to take any effect, it only changes the the password in rescue mode.

Here's some of the things I've tried

```
mount -o rw /dev/sda1 /mnt
chroot /mnt
passwd
reboot server to normal mode
```

&

```
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
chroot /mnt
nano /etc/shadow //changed the password with another one generated with openssl
reboot server
```

Here is `/proc/mounts` inside the recovery:
[image: /proc/mounts]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From looking at your [`cat /proc/mounts` output](https://ibb.co/krMcY5), it turns out your recovery system is on `/dev/sda1`, so you were changing the password for the recovery system (which presumably is ignored and the image discarded once you reboot). Your system has already been mounted at `/mnt/sdb1`.

It's also good practice to make sure the filesystem is cleanly unmounted, because I can't guarantee the "reboot my VPS" button does so.

```shell
chroot /mnt/sdb1
passwd
exit              # get out of chroot
umount /mnt/sdb1  # unmount the filesystem
sync              # just for paranoia
```

Then you can reboot it.